# Ajax won't pass to $_POST

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Having troubles passing the ajax to `$_POST`, it is always returning false.

***What I have tried so far:***

- Using contentType: `'application/json; charset=UTF-8'`,
- Creating a function for ajax and adding to jQuery onclick
- Removed dataType in Javascript, `console.log: Object {readyState: 0, responseText: "", status: 0, statusText: "error"}`
- With dataType in Javascript, `Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "↵
  ↵Failed to hold<br>", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}`

**Javascript:**

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#showcart").click(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    data: {'jCart':JSON.stringify(cart)},
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',   
                    url: 'storecart.php',
                    contentType:'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                    success: function(data){
                        console.log("Success")
                    },
                    error: errorFunction
                });

            }); 
        });

function errorFunction(){
    console.log("Error");
}
```

**Storecart.php**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['jCart'])){
        $decode = json_decode($_POST['jCart']);
        $_SESSION['receive'] = $decode;
        $product = $_SESSION['receive'];
    }
    else{
        echo "Failed to hold<br>";
    }
?>
```

**Cart.php**

```
<?php 
    session_store();
    include(Storecart.php);
?>
```

On the console, it will say `"Error"`.

On the cart.PHP, it will say `"Failed to hold"`.

What I know is that ajax is not running properly, I don't know how to fix it.

**ALMOST SOLUTION for ajax, but it can't post for some reason**

Don't know why but it worked for me.

Create a function:

```
function showcart(){
    var jData = JSON.stringify(cart);
    $.ajax({
        url:"storecart.php",
        type:"post",
        data: 'datastring=' + jData,
        datatype: "json",
        success: function(data){
            console.log("SUCCESS")
            console.log(jData);
        },
        error: function(data){
            console.log("REDO")
        }
    });     
}
```

Add it to the javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#showcart").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        showcart();
        }); 
    });
```

Comment: Try to edit your error callback and let us know what you see in the console. error: `function(data){ console.log(data); }`

Comment: @Sina `Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "↵
↵Failed to hold<br>", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}`

Comment: Try `method: 'POST'` instead of `type`.

Comment: @Sina nope doesn't wok

Comment: Try to remove your if condition `if(isset($_POST['jCart']))` and see what you get?

Comment: Undefined index: jCart

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(cart));` before your ajax call and let's see if you can see anything?

Comment: [{"name":"Please Like Me Season 2","price":22.5,"quantity":1},{"name":"Please Like Me Season 3","price":26.75,"quantity":1},{"name":"Please Like Me Season 1","price":17,"quantity":1}]

Comment: "Passing the ajax to $_POST"?

Answer (score 0):

You did not declare cart anywhere which is sending in data
data: {'jCart':JSON.stringify(cart)}

Comment: cart is declare in the javascript, didn't put it in this code

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code like this :

```
        var dataJcart = {
         "var": "example jcart"
        };
        var dataString = JSON.stringify(dataJcart);

          $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#showcart").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'storecart.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data:{'jCart': dataString},
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: errorFunction
            });

        }); 
    });
    function errorFunction(){
     console.log("Error non");
 }
```

Storecart.php

```
   if(isset($_POST["jCart"]))
    {
        $decode = json_decode($_POST["jCart"]);
        echo $decode->var;
    }
```